# $POST not sending checkbox values, PHP Undefined index error

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I'm new to PHP and Codeigniter. Trying to submit a form but the values are not being sent to the controller for some reason. If I don't use `isset` function then I get a Undefined index error. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<form action="<?= site_url('Buyer_Controller/view_cart') ?>" method= "post">

    <div class="lalign">
      <input type="checkbox" /> <span id="normal-p" name="coupon" value="sku_<?php echo html_escape($p_item2['CouponID']) ?>">;
</div>
<button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
public function view_cart()
    {

            $this->load->model("cart_model", "cartm");
            if (!empty($_SESSION['id']))
                redirect('Buyer_Controller');

               if(!isset($_POST['coupon'])) {

               redirect('Buyer_Controller/test');
               }

               else{

               $data= $_POST['coupon'];
               }

}
```

Comment: Checkbox has no `name` attribute.

Comment: Span has that `name` attribute instead of `input`. switch them

Comment: Thank you. I feel stupid. :(

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answers and comments are correct - you need to put the `name` attribute on your `input` - that will not solve your problem completely. You do need to change that though.

The other problem is that unchecked checkboxes are not sent to the server by the browser.

So you always need to use something like `isset()` or `empty()` when handling checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="normal-p" name="coupon" value="sku_<?php echo html_escape($p_item2['CouponID']) ?>">;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is wrong**

> **Errors**
>
> 1. Missing `name="coupon"` in `<input>`
> 2. Missing `{}` in `IF` statement
> 3. Missing `else` part of first IF condition

**Improves**

1. Fix the name field
2. Added `{}` in `IF`
3. Used `empty` instead of `isset`

---

```
<input type="checkbox" />  #  No Name attribute 
<span id="normal-p" name="coupon" value="sku_<?php echo html_escape($p_item2['CouponID']) ?>">
```

*It should be*

**In View**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="normal-p" name="coupon" value="sku_<?php echo html_escape($p_item2['CouponID']) ?>">
```

**In Controller**

```
public function view_cart()
{

    $this->load->model("cart_model", "cartm");

    if (!empty($_SESSION['id'])) # missing {}
    {
        redirect('Buyer_Controller');
    }
    else # Missing
    {
        $post = $this->input->post('coupon');
        if(!empty($post)) {
            redirect('Buyer_Controller/test');
        }
        else{
            $data = $post
        }
    }
}
```

> **Note**: Make sure your site is working without `index.php`

---

**References**

1. [HTML  checked Attribute - W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="coupon" value="sku_<?php echo html_escape($p_item2['CouponID']) ?>"/> <span id="normal-p"  value="sku_<?php echo html_escape($p_item2['CouponID']) ?>">;
```

change it like this ..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input type="checkbox" name="coupon" value="sku_<?php echo html_escape($p_item2['CouponID']) ?>" /> <span id="normal-p" for="coupon"> <?echo "sku_".html_escape($p_item2['CouponID']);?></span>
```